# Error in inherits(f, "fitdist") : object 'fitw' not found

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I am using R for modelling distributions with package `fitdistrplus`, I got a problem that

> Error in inherits(f, "fitdist") : object 'fitw' not found.

Attached is the code I am using for modelling. does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

```
library(fitdistrplus)

timegaplist = c(133408000, 150828000, 175692000, 96000, 143000, 169000, 207000, 
220000, 304000, 333000, 371000, 549000, 605000, 643000, 848000, 
874000, 907000, 935000, 1054000, 1068000, 1481000, 2082000, 2440000, 
2658000, 2836000, 3580000, 4138000, 4478000, 4536000, 4886000, 
6238000, 6532000, 6609000, 6676000, 6886000, 7742000, 7931000, 
8607000, 9186000, 9433000, 9575000, 9979000, 11139000, 13012000, 
13099000, 13220000, 13660000, 13849000, 15585000, 16787000, 17591000, 
18889000, 19169000, 19529000, 20863000, 22924000, 23463000, 24438000, 
25203000, 25364000, 25557000, 27173000, 27436000, 28769000, 30435000, 
31880000, 32342000, 33237000, 33497000, 34657000, 35227000, 35660000, 
36641000, 37488000, 38384000, 38930000, 38950000, 39652000, 41143000, 
44787000, 44979000, 45088000, 47357000, 52694000, 56774000, 59568000, 
70066000, 73901000, 76181000, 78820000, 1875073000, 197330000, 
197981000, 205765000, 216749000)


fitW = fitdist(timegaplist, "weibull",lower = c(0, 0))


gofw=gofstat(fitw)
wc=c(gofw$ks,gofw$kstest,gofw$aic,gofw$bic)
names(wc)=c("weibull.KS","weibull.KSTest","weibull.AIc","weibull.BIc")
```

Comment: ugh... check your case... `gofstat(fitW)` ie upper / lowercase `W`

Comment: Thanks! the problem is solved!  but I met another problems, which shows that   "Error in fitdist(timeGap[k:j], "exp") :   the function mle failed to estimate the parameters,      with the error code 100"

Comment: You're welcome. Re the error, that will be an error thrown by the optimiser, but I dont get an error using your example data, although I notice the estimates dont have st. error (im not familiar with this but that usually raises a flag). I wonder if it could be caused by the one large value?? Can you try and create an example that shows the new error please, and its probably best to ask it as a new question.. maybe of interest https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158163/why-does-this-data-throw-an-error-in-r-fitdistr